# Image viewer loads slowly or not at all with larger images 20.04

Tags: eog

Image Viewer / EoG seems to be the only affected program

The issue started recently.
Smaller images are loading a little slowly, greater than 10mb do not load at all, and seem to hang the program/ partially unresponsive for a short time.

Gimp has no issues.
Images greater than 100mb load fast within guest Win7 VM.
Saw a post about VM being an issue, tried without other programs open after restart, no change.
No memory/hd space issues could be found.

Fairly decent new laptop:
6 cores, SSD, 32 GB RAM
Host is Ubuntu 20.04

`free`:

```
             total        used        free      shared   buff/cache   available
Mem:       32513260    10739136    18834524     1092404     2939600    20213040
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

After reading that EoG is no longer maintained, I decided to go with [Nomacs](https://nomacs.org/)

Comment: VM? Virtualbox? Is Ubuntu the host OS in this case? Or Ubuntu is a guest on Windows?

Comment: I hate to ask (you have  32GB RAM), but do you need swao?  What does `free` show?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: In my experience Ubuntu image viewer is not very preformant. The fact that you can open the images in gimp with no issues proves that the slowness problem  comes from image viewer, not your hardware.